# How to remove the title bar from a form

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Does anyone know how to create a Delphi form without a title bar? I have seen some some links/tips but its not exactly what I want and I couldn't do it myself.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, set `BorderStyle`  to `bsNone` at design-time. Then declare the procedure `CreateParams` like so:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override; // ADD THIS LINE!
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
```

and implement it like

```
procedure TForm1.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.Style := Params.Style or WS_THICKFRAME;
end;
```

Comment: Does it look and behave properly also on Windows XP ? [+1]

Comment: @TLama: Don't remember and have no XP to test on, but there shouldn't be any problems, I think. (Doesn't it get a blue thick border instead of the glass one?)

Comment: Thanks Andreas, is there a way to modify the border size?

Comment: @HatemHidouri: That's an OS-wide setting (probably per-user).

Comment: I know this is a pretty old question, but just confirming: it does work in XP, although it does not create the regular blue thick border. Instead, it creates a grey thiner border (`Params.Style or WS_BORDER or WS_THICKFRAME` also does that). Still resizable thought.

Answer (score 3):

Set `BorderStyle` to `bsNone` in Object Inspector

Comment: That alone isn't sufficient.

Comment: Compare the result with the image supplied by the OP. The entire glass border (and shadow) is gone.

Answer (score 3):

For better border style, you can add the WS_BORDER flag.

Like this:

```html
procedure TForm1.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.Style := Params.Style or WS_BORDER or WS_THICKFRAME;
end;
```

Note than a soft line is drawn inside the border frame.